# Text randomly disappears while typing?

Tags: keyboard, macos, text, macbook-pro, text-input

rMBP OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

While chatting with friends on facebook, the text randomly disappears and appears at random intervals. I cannot induce the effect manually. It is very frustrating to see the text suddenly disappear yet show when I press enter.

Is there a specific reason ? Maybe spelling autocheck or autocorrect ?

**EDIT**

Any updates on this ?? Is there a fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same thing — there appears to be a rendering bug in Safari. Sometimes I see visual glitches when scrolling, too. It will probably be fixed in a software update in the future.

Comment: Note: be careful if you try to use Chrome as an alternative — there's some video rendering bug which freezes my entire system!

Comment: Hmm I thought I was the only one with a problem, thanks for the reply !

Comment: I also have delays before parts of pages are rendered when scrolling. But it could have something to do with `defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false`.

Answer (score 1):

Also experiencing the same thing.  I wonder if it has something to do with the autocorrect.  It is highly annoying though. It only happens in textareas that I've noticed.  Never seems to happen in single line form elements.

Comment: Comes and goes for me...Not sure why or when it happens